# Hiding rows in Sheet 2 based on Sheet 1 change

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet 1 containing information that are drawn into Sheet 2. Only Sheet 1 will be edited for future updates.

I would like to hide rows within a range in Sheet 2 that are "" or 0, based on Sheet 1 input.

This code (in Sheet 2) currently works for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Me.Range("P15:P22")
        If c.Value = 0 Or c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The only issue is that there is an obvious lag in loading the sheet.

To resolve this, I have tried moving the code to Sheet 1 instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    Sheet2.Activate

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Me.Range("P15:P22")
        If c.Value = 0 Or c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
    
    Sheet1.Activate

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This edit is not working for me. Upon a change in Sheet 1, the linked cell in Sheet is not updated and the relevant rows are not being hidden.

Could anyone kindly point out if there's an alternative approach to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does the result of `Sheet2!P15:P22` depend on values manually entered in `Sheet1` i.e. could you describe when the cells in `Sheet2` will be `""` or `0` i.e. could you share the formula (is it `=Sheet1!P15`)? You want to trigger the code as few times as possible. For example, the formula in `Sheet2!P15` is `=Sheet1!A15+Sheet1!B15` and you manually enter the values in `Sheet1!A15:B15`, then you could 'monitor' the `Sheet1!A15:B15` cells in the `Worksheet Change` event of `Sheet1`.

Comment: I am currently using an index match formula in Sheet 2 to draw out the relevant information from Sheet 1. Sheet 2 will only display relevant information from Sheet 1 based on user selection in Sheet 2 Cell E13. {=INDEX(Sheet1!$O$16:$R$25,MATCH(Sheet2!$E$13,Sheet1!$B$16:$B$25,0),1)} If the cell in Sheet 1 is empty, the corresponding output in Sheet 2 will be 0.